# Bootstrap 5 - problem changing column order

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm upgrading to Bootstrap 5 and can't get the column re-ordering to behave how I want. I have 3 columns: a title, an image, and a paragraph of text. On larger screens I want the image on the left with the title on the right and the paragraph of text directly below the title. On smaller screens, I want the three columns stacked vertically in the order of title, image, paragraph of text. Using .order I can mostly get things working how I want, except on larger screens I can't get the paragraph of text to appear directly below the title, rather it appears under the title but below the image albeit on the right. How can I push this third column up beside the image to appear directly below the title?

Here's my code so far:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-1 order-lg-2">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>title</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 order-2 order-lg-1">
      <div><img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="300"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-3 order-lg-3 ms-auto">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically not possible with display flex and order only.

So either you need to:

- Switch to grid
- Display with 2 different blocks or lines using `.d-{breakpoint}-{value}`

Bootstrap 5 [display doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/)

Different options, but the first is the most light:

### Option 1 - Added only 1 line and some display class

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-1 order-lg-2">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>title</p>
        <!--------------------->
        <!-- ADDED this line -->
        <!--------------------->
        <p class="d-none d-lg-block">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 order-2 order-lg-1">
      <div><img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="300"></div>
    </div>
    <!--------------------- ADDED d-lg-none -------------------------->
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-3 d-lg-none ms-auto">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 2 - Added only 1 block and some display classes

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-1 d-lg-none">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>title</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 order-2 order-lg-1">
      <div><img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="300"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-3 d-lg-none ms-auto">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ADDED block -->
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-4 order-lg-2 d-none d-lg-block">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>title</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 3 - Display grid

```css
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .grid-temp-1{
     grid-template: "a b" 0fr
                    "a c" 1fr
                    "a c" 1em / 33% 1fr;
  }
  .grid-temp-1 > div:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: b;
  }
  .grid-temp-1 > div:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: a;
  }
  .grid-temp-1 > div:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: c;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-lg-grid grid-temp-1">
    <div class="">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>title</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <div><img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="300"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="ms-auto">
      <div align="justify">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks kindly for this, it displays exactly how I want. I'm wondering if there's any way to do it without having to double up on the code that appears in the paragraph column? I have to replicate the solution over a number of pages and some have quite a lot of code - I'd rather not have to include it all twice but of course can live with the solution as the end user will only see the page as it's intended. I'm upgrading from Bootstrap 3 where it all worked fine mainly just by using .pull-right. Is that what you meant by 'switch to grid'?

Comment: You could by using `display:grid` but that would mean that you will need to write css instead of just using Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe I'll look into this. In the end, writing some CSS will probably be less than doubling up on the paragraph text, and it will also make updating the page less troublesome.

Comment: @Dr_Hoon Here I created a basic example with display grid, and no need of any class in your siblings div, only in your `row` to switch to grid.

Comment: Thanks heaps @MaxiGui, this works great. Amazing work. Your solution is way above my understanding of CSS and I couldn't have done it by myself. I looked back over my Bootstrap 3 code and achieved the same thing just by using the .pull-right class on the two columns of text - I guess for all the upgrades, they made certain things so much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Go with two column layout. You can nest the heading and the paragraph inside one column.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 order-1 order-lg-2">
            <div align="justify">
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>
            <div align="justify">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 order-2 order-lg-1">
            <div><img src="image.png" width="200" height="300"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks fine on larger screens, however I want the image to appear between the heading and the paragraph when the breakpoint rearranges columns for mobile devices.